# Checkbox not rendering according to state value

Tags: checkbox, state, react-native, react-native-ios

I have to change the Checkbox UI from Check to Uncheck and vice versa according to the value of the state : checked.

For that I have used **'react-native-elements'**.

My state name is **checked**

I have also taken two Buttons to change the state value, but the checkbox is not rendering according to value of the state.

I have done as below : Please guide.

Thanks.

> > > > > 

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checked: true,
    }
 }

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

<CheckBox
  title='Click Here'
  checked={this.state.checked}
/>

<CheckBox
  center
  title='Click Here'
  checked={this.state.checked}
/>

  <Button value="Check"
       title="Check"
          onPress={()=>{
            this.state.checked=true;
            Alert.alert("State >>"+this.state.checked);
          }}
       />

       <Button value="Un-Check"
       title="Un-Check"
          onPress={()=>{
            this.state.checked=false;
            Alert.alert("State >"+this.state.checked);
          }}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT

I have done as below :

```
<Button value="Check"
       title="Check"
          onPress={()=>{

            this.setState((prevState,props)=>({
              isChecked=prevState.isChecked
            }));
            //this.state.isChecked=true;
            Alert.alert("State >>"+this.state.isChecked);
          }}
       />
```

**But, It gives me syntax error : 
Unexpected Token (81:23)**

Comment: change isChecked=prevState.isChecked  to isChecked : !prevState.isChecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
 this.state.isChecked=true;
```

with

```
 this.setState({
    isChecked : true
   })
```

You can not assign value directly to the `state` for that you have to use `setState({})`  so update you `state` as mentioned above

for false use

```
 this.setState({
        isChecked : false
       })
```

**For EDIT  section**

```
  this.setState((prevState,props)=>({
          isChecked : prevState.isChecked
        }));
```

Use `:` inside `stae`  do not use `=`  it will give sintext error..

Comment: will you pls. check EDIT section. I have edited as in EDIT

Comment: change   isChecked=prevState.isChecked   to   isChecked: !prevState.isChecked

Comment: Wooo... Its done sir, The mistake was, I have to use :(colon). tx.

Answer (score 2):

Your onPress in wrong. you need `setState`. In addition to @Jay 's Answer,

`setState` is asynchronous, meaning if you press the checkbox multiple timesm, things can get messed up.So the best way is to get the `prevState` and mutate it instead

For eg: Toggling the state to and fro like in a checkbox

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  isChecked: prevState.isChecked 
}));
```

Comment: will you pls. check EDIT section. I have edited as in EDIT